# Clickhouse server error - org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1

Tags: clickhouse

I am getting this error when i am trying to restart my clickhouse server.

```
Failed to start clickhouse-server.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status clickhouse-server.service' for details.
```

Upon further inspection of server. We noticed that Log directory was full. After flushing the logs clickhouse server restarted normally. But the error message made no sense cite the actual problem. then what is this error pointing to ? Pls enlight

Comment: This issue has no relation to CH. This error message is from SystemD https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22The+name+org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1+was+not+provided+by+any+.service%22

Answer (score 1):

org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 , is like sudo but for systemd. It should be enabled for systemd to work. Resolved it by accessing ec2 superuser privelage.
sudo su